# AR.JS redirection after marker identification

Tags: augmented-reality, ar.js

I have a question related to augmented reality using AR.js.
How can I redirect an user to another page once the specified marker has been identified, I tried using A-frame also but no help.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the big problems with AR.js.  There is a [pull request](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/pull/303/commits/2e61cdc43b2a9cf30f1abb3e754c8381730cb7e8) up that has not been merged that would fix this problem.  You can take a look and make similar edits in the library yourself to get an event to trigger your page redirect.